# Menu com hover CSS

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web e gostaria de que quando passar o mouse por cima do `<h4 class="entre">Entre/Cadastre-se</h4>` mostrasse o  menu da classe com nome `<div class="conteudo_dropdow"></div>`.

```css
@media  (max-width: 730px) {
.cadastro:hover{
 background:rgb(44,62,80);
 border:rgb(44,62,80);
 color: white;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
   -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
 
}

 .conteudo a:hover{
    font-size: 14pt;
color: blue;
  font-family: 'Fixation';
          
        }


        .conteudo a:link {
            color: black;
  font-family: 'Fixation';
            text-decoration: none; 
           
        }

        .conteudo a:visited { 
   color: black;
  font-family: 'Fixation';
            
          
        }
        .conteudo a :active {
           color: black;
  font-family: 'Fixation';
            color: #00008B;
        }
.cadastrese{
  font-family: 'Fixation';
 font-size: 15pt;
 margin-left: 300px;
 margin-top: -160px;
}
.cadastro{
 margin-left: 340px;
 margin-top: 16px;
 background-color: white;
 width: 130px;
 height: 45px;
 color: black;
 font-weight: 700;
 border-radius: 5px;
}

.caixa{
 
 border: 1px solid #dedddd;
 margin-rigth: 2500px;
 padding: 32px;
}
.caixa_componentes{
 margin-top: 10px;
 
}
}
```

```html
 <header>
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3">
<button type="button" class="botao_menu_celular">MENU</button><img src="imagens/bolos.JPG" class="imagem_header">
   </div>
   
   <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3">
<div class="campo_busca"><input type="text"id="busca"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div>
   </div>
   
   <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3">
<h4 class="entre">Entre/Cadastre-se</h4> 
   </div>
  
   
    
   <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3">
 <h4 class="fale">Duvidas/Fale conosco</h4> 
   </div>
   
   </div>
  </div>
 </header>
  
  
   <div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="conteudo_dropdow">
 
  <ul class="caixa">
  <div class="conteudo"><li ><a href="#">Meus Pedidos</a></li></div> 
  <div class="conteudo">  <li class="caixa_componentes"><a href="#">Efetuar Login</a></li></div> 
  <div class="conteudo"> <li class="caixa_componentes"><a href="#">Alterar Dados</a></li></div> 
  <div class="conteudo"> <li class="caixa_componentes"><a href="#">Sair</a></li></div> 
   
  </ul>
  <h4 class="cadastrese">Não é Cadastrado? Cadastre-se</h4>
<button type="button" class="cadastro">Cadastro</button>
  
 </div>

 </div>
 </div>
```

Ao passar o mouse por cima do Entre/Cadastre-se o sub-menu aparece.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao ir até o sub-menu, o sub-menu desaparece

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro é preciso esconder de início o `.conteudo_dropdow` adicionando no CSS:

```
.conteudo_dropdow{
   display: none;
}
```

Em seguida você pode usar o método `mouseenter` para abrir o submenu e o `mouseleave` para esconder:

```js
$(".col-xs-3.col-md-3 .entre").on("mouseenter", function(){
    $(".conteudo_dropdow").show();
});

$("div.conteudo_dropdow").on("mouseleave", function(){
    $(".conteudo_dropdow").hide();
});
```

```css
@media  (max-width: 730px) {
.cadastro:hover{
background:rgb(44,62,80);
border:rgb(44,62,80);
color: white;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.conteudo a:hover{
font-size: 14pt;
color: blue;
font-family: 'Fixation';
}

.conteudo a:link {
color: black;
font-family: 'Fixation';
text-decoration: none; 
}

.conteudo a:visited { 
color: black;
font-family: 'Fixation';
}

.conteudo a :active {
color: black;
font-family: 'Fixation';
color: #00008B;
}

.cadastrese{
font-family: 'Fixation';
font-size: 15pt;
margin-left: 300px;
margin-top: -160px;
}

.cadastro{
margin-left: 340px;
margin-top: 16px;
background-color: white;
width: 130px;
height: 45px;
color: black;
font-weight: 700;
border-radius: 5px;
}

.caixa{
border: 1px solid #dedddd;
margin-rigth: 2500px;
padding: 32px;
}
.caixa_componentes{
margin-top: 10px;
}
}

.conteudo_dropdow{
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3">
<button type="button" class="botao_menu_celular">MENU</button><img src="imagens/bolos.JPG" class="imagem_header">
</div>

<div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3">
<div class="campo_busca"><input type="text"id="busca"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3">
<h4 class="entre">Entre/Cadastre-se</h4> 
</div>
<div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3">
<h4 class="fale">Duvidas/Fale conosco</h4> 
</div>
</div>
</div>
</header>

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="conteudo_dropdow">

<ul class="caixa">
<div class="conteudo"><li ><a href="#">Meus Pedidos</a></li></div> 
<div class="conteudo">  <li class="caixa_componentes"><a href="#">Efetuar Login</a></li></div> 
<div class="conteudo"> <li class="caixa_componentes"><a href="#">Alterar Dados</a></li></div> 
<div class="conteudo"> <li class="caixa_componentes"><a href="#">Sair</a></li></div> 

</ul>
<h4 class="cadastrese">Não é Cadastrado? Cadastre-se</h4>
<button type="button" class="cadastro">Cadastro</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Se quiser usar algum efeito, pode substituir o `.show()` por `.slideDown()` ou `.fadeIn()`, por exemplo.

Comment: dá para fazer só com CSS mesmo o elemento target não sendo irmão?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo Cara, creio que não. Só conheço `+` (seguinte), `~` (irmãos) e `>` (filhos)

Comment: dvd ele funcionou, mas não do jeito que eu queria gostaria , quando eu  passo o mouse sobre o entre/cadastre-se ele mostra o submenu, mas quando eu tiro o mouse de cima do entre/cadastre-se o sub menu continua visível, gostaria de que quando eu tirar o mouse do submenu, o submenu saísse. link com o problema https://jsfiddle.net/v718rxtg/44/

Comment: @User1999 Atualizei a resposta com um pequeno código que esconde o submenu.

Comment: @dvd só que acontece um problema,quando eu vou posicionar o mouse ate o sub-menu o, sub-menu desaparece atualizei a pergunta com a imagem com o erro